# Finitely many simple modules over finite-dimensional algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory

I am going through Alperin's "Local Representation Theory" and I got stuck in the very beginning.

We have $k$ - algebraically closed field and $A$ - a finite-dimesnional algebra over $k$ (I'm not sure either what does it mean - finitely dimensional as vector space or of finite Krull dimension?). Now the book is saying that there are only finitely many simple $A$- modules up to is, since $A$ has a composition series as a $A$-module and every simple module is a composition factor.

I understand the latter, but I cannot see why from existence of composition series follows finite number of simple modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the algebra is finite-dimensional, that means $A$ has finite dimension over $k$ as a vector space. This implies that the Jacobson radical $rad(A)$ is nilpotent and $A/rad(A)$ is semisimple so it has a finite number of simple modules. Since every simple module over $A$ is a simple module over $A/rad(A)$, then we can conclude that there are finitely many simple modules over $A$.

Answering the last part of your question, if $A$ has a composition series and $S$ is any nonzero simple module, then there is an epimorphism $A\rightarrow S$, and this implies that $S$ is isomorphic to one of the composition factors of $A$. This also implies that there is a finite number of simples up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for that! But how can I see that in the given situation $rad(A)$ is nilpotent?

Comment: Consider the sequence $A\supset rad(A)\supset rad^2(A)\supset\cdots$ which is formed of proper inclusions (verify this). Use that the dimension over $k$ is finite to conclude that for some power $n$ we get $rad^n(A)=0.$ This argument follows almost line by line in the more general case that $A$ is an Artin algebra.